# DDD - Enity Framework 4 and ncommon

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, ddd-repositories, ncommon

I'm trying to get EF4 working with ncommon 1.1 which provides DDD patterns such as UnitOfWork, Specification, Repository.

The NCommon configuration line is throwing the following Exception:

SynchronizationLockException occurred

Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.

The actual code throwing the error is:

```
.ConfigureData<EFConfiguration>(config => config.WithObjectContext(() => new CoreContext(connectionString)))
```

Here is the code that I am running.

```
private static void ConfigureIoc()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        var serviceLocator = new UnityServiceLocator(container);
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => serviceLocator);

        container
            .RegisterType(typeof(IUnitOfWorkScope), typeof(UnitOfWorkScope), new InjectionConstructor())
            .RegisterType(typeof(IList<>), typeof(List<>), new InjectionConstructor())
            .RegisterType<IVerticalRepository, EfVerticalRepository>()
            ;

        const string connectionString = 
               @"metadata=res://*/Core.csdl|res://*/Core.ssdl|res://*/Core.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="";Data Source=devdatabase;Initial Catalog=InfoChoiceAdmin;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa;MultipleActiveResultSets=True""";

        var adapter = new UnityContainerAdapter(container);

        NCommon.Configure.Using(adapter)
            .ConfigureState<DefaultStateConfiguration>()
            .ConfigureData<EFConfiguration>(config => config.WithObjectContext(() => new CoreContext(connectionString)))
            .ConfigureUnitOfWork<DefaultUnitOfWorkConfiguration>(config => config.AutoCompleteScope());

        Ioc.Initialize(serviceLocator);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try it on other computer? I'm asking because last week I had similar strange exception in project using Unity. Without any changes in code project stopped working just only on my computer. I had to delete whole solution from my computer and remove workspace form TFS. Then I created new workspace and downloaded solution and it worked.

Comment: Thank-you for the response, I have tried it on another computer with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

David,

Could you post the exact stack trace of the exception? What I suspect is there's something strange going on during the object context's construction.

In NCommon when you call config.WithObjectContext(() => new CoreContext(connectionString)), it is internally creating an instance of the context to inspect it's MetadataWorkSpace. If you could also provide me with a repro sample it would help track down this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException occurred
  Message=Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
  Source=Microsoft.Practices.Unity
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.SynchronizedLifetimeManager.TryExit() in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\Lifetime\SynchronizedLifetimeManager.cs:line 109
  InnerException:

Comment: Thanx for your help Ritesh, I ended up deleting the project and re-loading from SVN and it all worked.